# Is it possible in postgres to auto increment by "category", or the value of some other field?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, uniqueidentifier

I have a 10 categories and I would like to have an auto increment field that basically counts its sequential position based on the category field.

For example if I have a table of shirts, and category field that could be 'green', 'blue' or 'black', could I have an auto increment field 'category_sequence' that would start at 1 and auto increment for each category?

For example the first green shirt would have category_sequence of 1, and the first black shirt would also be 1. But the next green shirt would auto increment to 2...

This situation is clearly over simplified, and the issue we're trying to solve is giving unique sequential ids by category in a system that that might get duplicates due to race conditions if handled by the app itself.

We're trying to piggy-back on the db if possible as the sole source of truth for this.

Comment: This has been addressed here a number of times, search the history on the postgresql tag. Short version: Use a side table with a counter. See, e.g. this closely related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29596980/398670, http://stackoverflow.com/q/32382512/398670

Comment: Further research has lead me to find sequences. I haven't fully read through this, but it looks interesting at a minimum, and may be promising: nextval('foo') http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-sequence.html